# Translating a ternary operation to an if/else statement?

Tags: java

I have the following boolean method in Java, but I can't understand its return statement because it uses a ternary operation. Can anyone rewrite it to an if/else statement so that I can better understand what the ternary operation is doing?

```
    public boolean collidesWith(Rectangle object){
    return (isDestroyed)? false:hitbox.intersects(object);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I can. But I won't do it since you need to learn what it means, and currently it's way better than using `if-else`.

Comment: What is "way better", learning a new thing or using one construct over the other? If the latter, then in this particular case or whenever the assignment to a variable depends on a boolean expression, I agree with you. In all other cases though, I would be careful to say one construct is better than the other. It depends on so many things, not the least what the author find to be readable code given the particular context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ternary operator is a short-hand for writing an if-else statement. Its general for is

```
<boolean condition to evaluate> ? 
    <return value if condition is true - i.e., the "if" branch > : 
    <return value is condition is false - i.e., the "else" branch>
```

So, if you unwrap the method you showed, you'd get:

```
public boolean collidesWith(Rectangle object){
    if (isDestroyed) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return hitbox.intersects(object);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, here is how I would write the method you posted (adding whitespace):

```
public boolean collidesWith(Rectangle object) {
    return isDestroyed ? false : hitbox.intersects(object);
}
```

Here is the if-else you're looking for:

```
public boolean collidesWith(Rectangle object) {
    if (isDestroyed) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return hitbox.intersects(object);
    }
}
```

..or a bit simplified:

```
public boolean collidesWith(Rectangle object) {
    if (isDestroyed)
        return false;

    return hitbox.intersects(object);
}
```

You may also make the ternary operator look a bit like an if-else:

```
public boolean collidesWith(Rectangle object) {
    return isDestroyed ?
        false :
        hitbox.intersects(object);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
public boolean collidesWith(Rectangle object){
      if(isDestroyed)   
          return false;
      else              
          return hitbox.intersects(object);

}
```

Comment: By the way, there's no need of `else`.